# Does Psalm 19 lack any reference to the fifth commandment to honor one's parents?

Tags: psalms, ten-commandments

In studying Psalm 19, which extols God's law, I have found positive or negative references to nine of the Ten Commandments, the sole exception being the commandment to honor your father and mother. For example:

> More to be desired are they than gold, even much fine gold; sweeter also than honey and drippings of the honeycomb. (Psalm 19:10)

The first half of the verse is a counter for covetousness, as the psalmist tells us that God's law is more precious than anything, even our neighbor's goods. The second half deals with adultery, by comparison to Proverbs, which speaks of honey in a seductive way:

> For the lips of a forbidden woman drip honey, and her speech is smoother than oil... (Proverbs 5:3)

Another example is found here:

> The law of the Lord is perfect, reviving the soul; the testimony of the Lord is sure, making wise the simple; (Psalm 19:7)

What revives the soul like the rest of the Sabbath? What testimony is more admirable in court than that of a true witness, not one bearing false witness?

My question is this:

By Hebrew phrasing or idiom, is there a connection to honoring fathers or mothers in this psalm that I have overlooked? For example, we have the analogy of the bridegroom and tent. Does it reference something cultural that implicitly honors one's parents? Or does any of the phrasing of the psalm explicitly speak of God as a father?

Comment: This is a highly interpretive question and not really a hermeneutical question.